# javascript removing event listeners

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Is the following actually removing the event before destroying the element? I can't figure out in the DOM inspector what functions are attached and if they're removed after running the following code:

```
el.addEventListener('click', function attachFunction (a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}, false);

el.removeEventListener('click', attachFunction, false);
```

Comment: It does not remove the event handler, it probably produces an error as the `attachFunction` is not defined in the scope you're trying to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as it stands, your code will not work

> **Note:** To remove event handlers, the function specified with the addEventListener() method must be an external function.

<sup>[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) <s>[w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)</s> -(sorry, but sometimes w3fools does provide just what you wanted)</sup>

So, you would need to do this instead:

```
function attachFunction(a, b){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

el.addEventListener('click', attachFunction, false);

el.removeEventListener('click', attachFunction, false);
```

which will work as expected.

If you want to pass certain arguments to your function `attachFunction`, you'll need to use another function:

```
function attachFunction(a, b){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
}

function linkFunction(){
  attachFunction(a, b); // a and b can be replaced with anything you want
}

el.addEventListener('click', linkFunction, false);

el.removeEventListener('click', linkFunction, false);
```

Comment: But how about the parameters?

Comment: how do I send the parameters inside addEventListener?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand; how about them? If you tell me what they should be set to, I can fix it, but currently my args are the same as yours.

Comment: I mean: el.addEventListener('click', attachFunction(a, b), false);

Comment: @poashoas what do you want them set to?

Comment: never mind, I think I declare the variables somewhere and get them inside that functions, thanks anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74426/discussion-between-poashoas-and-theonlygusti).

Comment: What if you want access to the event object? How can you pass that in?

Comment: @LorenShqipognja the first argument to `attachFunction` (in this case `a`) is by default the event object. So, `el.addEventListener('click', function(event){console.log(event)}, false);` would log the event object every time that the element is clicked.

Comment: So even when using a named function instead of anonymous, in which we do not explicitly declare in the signature that the event "e" is a parameter, the first item in the arguments object of the function will always be the event?

Comment: @LorenShqipognja yes, exactly. Be careful with your terminaology though, should be: "the first item in the arguments **array** of the function will always be the event **object**."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to remove an event listener added with `addEventListener`, define it external to the `addEventListener()` call:

```
function attachFunction (a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}
```

then:

```
el.addEventListener("click", attachFunction);
```

Then your `.removeEventListener()` can work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `function foo(whatever)` is evaluated before the runtime, so Idon't think your code is a valid syntax or will have the expected behaviour. You should better use an anonymous function like this:

```
var attachFunction = function(a, b) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}
el.addEventListener('click', attachFunction, false);
el.removeEventListener('click', attachFunction, false);
```

Please also note that an event listener (here `attachFunction`) can only have a single argument which is the event object.

Comment: "evaluated before the runtime" -- I'm pretty sure that's not true.

Comment: It is valid; function instantiation expressions like that can have names, though the semantics are different than those of function declaration statements.

Answer (score 0):

The `function` keyword can be used two ways: as a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).  There is a discussion of the differences [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression), but I'll try to cover the relevant parts.

When used as a statement (as below), the function name will be valid within the surrounding scope of the statement:

```
function hi(){ 
    console.log(typeof hi); // "function"
}
console.log(typeof hi); // "function"
```

But when used as an expression, the function name is only valid *within* the function body:

```
var greetings = function hi(){ 
    console.log(typeof hi); // "function"
}
console.log(typeof hi); // "undefined"
console.log(typeof greetings); // "undefined
```

So the scope problem with your initial example is that, because you are using it as an expression, the name `attachFunction` will be undefined when you try to unbind it.

(I think you also have some confusion about how parameters are passed to event handlers, but that's a separate issue.)